# Break long lines in contenteditable div flex-item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, contenteditable

I am trying to make my contenteditable div to do a couple of things:

1. Take all the horizontal space left between the div and the button
2. Wrap when the line become too long between words
3. Wrap at the middle of the word only if it is a single long word

I get either 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 to work, but never the 3 options.

If I use

```
word-break:break-all;
```

it works for long words, but doesn't wrap between words when I have a normal sentence.

If I don't use it, it cuts between words, but not anymore on a very long word.

It works as expected if I use on chrome:

```
word-break:break-word;
```

but that doesn't seem to be a standard argument.

```css
article {
  display:flex;
  background-color:red;
  padding:1em 1em 1em 1em;
}
div {
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #000;
  flex:1 0 0px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    Should cut only on space here mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
  </div>
  <span>SEND</span>
</article>
<br>
<br>
<article>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    Should_cut_anywhere_here_mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
  </div>
  <span>SEND</span>
</article>
```

Comment: So it should cut and break to a new line?

Comment: My goal is to cut in a "smart" way. Priority cut between words (if necessary because line is too long) and only cut at the middle of a word if there is no space to do the cut.